# magento email template format for contact page comment text area field

Tags: magento-1.7

In my magneto site have contact form and form is submitted successfully, but Comment text area field content show in one line.
Suppose customer write like this(with line break) -

```
Hello,
I would like to get a price for the product XY.
Thanks a lot for your help.
Best regards
John.
```

but in email I get like this-

```
 Hello, I would like to get a price for the product XY. Thanks a lot for your help.
Best regards John.
```

I am using this code

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Please tell me what i do ?
Thanks

Comment: Hello Sam, Thanks, can you tell me that how i fix this issue ?

Comment: Any one can help me i am tired to search.                                                   Please help me.

Comment: No any one is there, who know about it ?                                                    I am feeling great because i have 1 year experience and i am equal level with others who have 5-10 years experience.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We are having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this you should use the System > Transaction emails option in Magento admin.

Add a new template, select contact form and load template. When you have created the template make sure the template type is TEXT and not HTML.  If it is HTML you will not get the line breaks.  You can open the template and click Convert to Plain Text if it is in HTML.

Once it is created go to System > Config > Contacts > Email Template and select the template you just created.